# How to move a module on page to my own custom module placeholder?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am developing a DNN module which is a grid with 50 rows on each page.
In some specific rows I would like to embed Ad module which is a 3rd party module.

I want to be able to add Ad module to the page individually, then configure it and then in the code behind of my Grid module, move Ad module to a place holder that is located on some of the grid rows.

Is it doable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with server side code but it should be fairly easy to do using Javascript/jQuery. Take a look at the Moving Elements Around section on [this page](http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-removing-replacing-moving-elements/).

Comment: Thanks for reply. There is a DNN module called Aggregator that is basically a tab module and any module on the page can be moved to the tab sheets. So, I believe this is somehow possible. My only concern about jQuery is what if javascript is disabled on the client's browser?